# Determine Huffman Tree Depth Using any combinactory ways?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, algorithms, computer-science, trees

I see [this link](http://ipnpr.jpl.nasa.gov/progress_report/42-110/110N.PDF) for determining depth (height) of Huffman tree, but not useful for me.

My Question is: Knowing the frequencies of each symbol, is it possible to determine the maximum height or exactly determine the height of the tree without applying the Huffman algorithm? Is there a formula that gives this tree height?

for Example: 10-Input Symbol with Frequency 1 to 10 is 5. the above question mentioned depth is 5.

We know in my specific example the frequency is: $1$ to $10$ which means probability is: $(1/55)+(2/55)+(3/55)+(4/55)+(5/55)+(6/55)+(7/55)+(8/55)+(9/55)+(10/55) = 1 $

Comment: Can you explain more why running the Huffman algorithm isn't useful for you? If you're willing to look at all the frequencies, that takes $\Theta(n)$ work just to read in the data. The complexity of the Huffman algorithm is $\Theta(n)$ as well; since you've already done that much work to read in the data, you might as well run it. On the other hand, perhaps you're looking for an algorithm which takes as input $o(n)$ data *about* your frequencies, and runs in $o(n)$ time. In this case it would be helpful to know what you're willing to assume about your frequencies.

Comment: @Tad this is an interview question that should be rapidly answered, not by drawing tree.

Comment: If I were asked this in an interview, I'd just give the height in the best case ($\lg n$ if the $n$ frequencies are equal), and worst case ($n-1$ if the frequencies are superincreasing.)

Comment: @Tad you are so expert, but in this specific example I need more hint.

Comment: Work out two Huffman trees. Do it for 16 symbols all with frequency 1, and then for the frequencies 1,2,4,8,16,32. You'll learn from the first case that $2^n$ symbols with the same frequency give a Huffman tree of height $n$ (so the height is the log of the number of symbols). And the second case is as bad as it gets - every new symbol you add increases the height by one.

Comment: I know very well your examples @Tad